# How to distinguish a causal chain model from a double effect model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, causality, linear

I am used a linear mixed model on two datasets (two different species), with the same explanatory variable (an environmental variable) for fixed effects.

I then select the top 0.1% response variables most associated with the explanatory variable (according to their Z-scores) in both datasets.

The response variables are tranformed (Hellinger transformation) counts of alleles (gene forms) for many sites in the genome (genetic material of an organism) of thousands of individuals.

I have now two sets of genetic sites for two different species that are putatively associated with the explanatory variable I am interested in.

Those sets will show co-variation. However, a professor just made me realize that this co-variation could be due to either:

- a double causal effect

[image]

- a causal chain

[image]

Do you have any idea of how I could tell those to hypotheses apart?

Here are a few code lines which create an fake environmental variable and two fake genetic datasets (10 genetic sites for 1000 individuals)for two species:

```
#environment
env_var<-sort(abs(rnorm(1000,10,10)));

#species 1
sp1<-matrix(data=NA,1000,10)
for (i in 1:10){ # Number of columns
    sp1[,i]<-sort(abs(rnorm(1000,100,10)))
}
sp1

#species 2
sp2<-matrix(data=NA,1000,10)
for (i in 1:10){ # Number of columns
  sp2[,i]<-sort(abs(rnorm(1000,100,10)))
}
sp2

library(rdaTest)

rdaTest(Y=sp2,X=env_var,W=sp1,test.F=TRUE,nperm=1000);
rdaTest(Y=sp1,X=env_var,W=sp2,test.F=TRUE,nperm=1000);
```

The only thing I have thought of as you can see is partial canonical redundancy analysis but it may not enable me to choose between the two illustrated hypotheses stated earlier.

Comment: Is it possible that the true model is a combination of both of your hypotheses? That is, there's an effect of the environmental variable on both species, and an additional effect of on species on the other? Also, just so I understand the context, how are you envisioning the genetic sites in one species interacting with the genetic sites in the other - is one a predator of the other, for example?

Comment: If I take the models you've drawn at face value, they can be distinguished using conditional independence tests, but I want to make sure I understand the whole setup

Comment: It could be possible that the true model would be a combination of both my hypotheses, that is a non-cyclic triangular relationship. Genetic sites of a species could be interacting with genetic sites of another species if co-evolution is happening, i.e. when species genomes reciprocally affect each other.